# Using a variable as an argument

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering if it is possible to use a variable as an argument in this case.

This is the code that I have:

```
def text_get_position(x, y, position):

    if position == "midleft":
        text_position = text_to_screen.get_rect(midleft=(x, y))
    elif position == "midright":
        text_position = text_to_screen.get_rect(midright=(x, y))
    else:
        text_position = text_to_screen.get_rect(center=(x, y))
```

I want to do something like:

```
def text_get_position(x, y, position):
        text_position = text_to_screen.get_rect(position=(x, y))
```

I am sorry if it is already asked but I tried to look around and couldn't find a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the named ("keyword") arguments as a dictionary. Note the `**` in front of the dictionary.

```
def text_get_position(x, y, position):
    text_position = text_to_screen.get_rect(**{position: (x, y)})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for.